# what is concept of getMinimumSize, getPreferredSize, and getMaximumSize methods.

Tags: java, swing

I am done with sun documentation but still not able to figure out what these three methods (getMinimumSize, getPreferredSize, and getMaximumSize) actually do with different layouts please help me get basic.

Comment: Different LayoutManagers will use this information differently. Some will honor the min size, some won't. Some will honor the preferred size some won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty contextual, but basically the `getMinimumSize`, `getPreferredSize` and `getMaximumSize` provide sizing "hints" to the layout management API.

Each layout may use none or more of this methods to make determinations about how a component may be layed out.

For example, `BorderLayout` will use the preferred size value, but doesn't pay much attention to the others.  `GridBagLayout` can make use of just about all the values, but they can be overridden by various constraints.

You could take a look through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and try some experminetion

Answer (score 1):

The methods starting with get will simply return what the minimum size, preferred size and maximum size of the component are.

Setting these values react differently with different objects. Setting the maximum size will say that you do not want said component larger than the Dimension passed in.

Same goes for preferred size and maximum size, stating that you would like the component to be preferred size and no bigger than maximum size.

I suggest you experiment yourself with these values, multiple components in a new class. Practice makes perfect.